# HTML spidering to ePub conversion tool

Tags: html, parsing, epub

It appears that there is currently no tool available for spidering a site and converting the contents to ePub format. I suppose there are legal implications on performing this action on a site without express consent from the site owner.

The reason I ask, is that I would like to be able to convert the Doctrine 2 reference guide into ePub format for my Kindle.

Comment: Does the kindle support ePub?

Comment: Calibre can be used to convert and push ePub files to the Kindle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often better to find out what the documentation sources are and use those. In the case of the doctrine 2 they are [RST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/introduction.html) text files. The docutils tools (written in Python) converts these to various forms, such as the website you see. The [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/index.html) documentation builder builds on that, and that appears to be what they use. It so happens that they have an [ePub builder](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/builders.html#sphinx.builders.epub.EpubBuilder).

Since it's an open source project the sources are [readily available](http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/DoctrineORM-2.0.4-full.tar.gz). Or you can get the latest from their git repository `git clone git://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git doctrine2-orm`.

This is the easiest, most direct route to getting the documentation on your Kindle.

Comment: @Richard, did you managed to convert this to ePub format? Could you share it?

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that there is currently no tool available for spidering a site and converting the contents to ePub format.

You should check http://web2fb2.net/.

Not perfect (I didn't manage to get intra-links working), but it can do the job.